# sed match only first expression

Tags: bash, sed

I'm doing a parser for build outputs, and I'd like to highlight different patterns in different colors.   So for example, I'd like to do:

```
sed -e "s|\(Error=errcode1\)|<red>\1<_red>|" \
    -e "s|\(Error=errcode2\)|<orange>\1<_orange>|" \
    -e "s|\(Error=.*\)|<blue>\1<_blue>|"
```

(so it higlights errcode1 in red, errcode2 in orange, and anything else in blue).   The problem with this is that `Error=errcode1` matches both the first and the third expression, which will result in `<red><blue>Error=errcode1<_red><_blue>`...   Is there any way to tell sed to match only the first expression, and if it does, do not try the following expressions?

Note, the sed command will actually be auto-generated from files which will be very volatile, so I'd like a generic solution where I don't have to police whether patterns conflict...

Comment: Does it have to be with sed? Would you be interested in a solution using Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with a simpler example to illustrate the problem.  In the code below, both substitutions are performed:

```
$ echo 'error' | sed 's/error/error2/; s/error/error3/'
error32
```

If we want to skip the second if the first succeeded, we can use the "test" command which branches if the previous substitution was successful.  If we provide no label after `t`, it branches to the end, skipping all remaining commands:

```
$ echo 'error' | sed 's/error/error2/; t; s/error/error3/'
error2
```

#### Summary

If you want to stop after the first substitution that succeeds, place a `t` command after each substitution command.

#### More complex case

Suppose that we want to skip the second but not the third substitution if the first succeeds.  In that case, we need to supply a label to the `t` command:

```
$ echo 'error' | sed 's/error/error2/; ta; s/error/error3/; :a; s/error/error4/'
error42
```

In the above, `:a` defines label `a`.  The command `ta` branches to label `a` if the preceeding `s` command succeeds.

#### Compatibility

The above code was tested in GNU sed.  I am told that BSD sed does not accept `;` as a command separator after a label.  Thus, on BSD/macOS, try:

```
echo 'error' | sed -e 's/error/error2/' -e ta -e 's/error/error3/' -e :a -e 's/error/error4/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply boolean logic to matches with `|`, `&` and `!`.

### Solution

(not sure if the syntax is compatible with your system so you may need to add more backslashes)

```
"s|\(Error=\(.*&!errcode1&!errcode2\)\)|<blue>\1<_blue>|"
```

### Other notes

`sed` can use any character as a delimiter, so all of the following expressions are equivalent:

```
"s/foo/bar/"
"s:foo:bar:"
"s|foo|bar|"
"s#foo#bar#"
```

Also, if you are using `bash` on a Unix-based system, you can use shell variables if you're running this from a script (since your patterns are enclosed with `"` and not `'`, there's a difference).

```
PREFIX="Error="
TARGET_1="errorcode1"
TARGET_2="errorcode2"

SUB_1="<red>\1<_red>"
SUB_2="<orange>\1<_orange>"
SUB_3="<blue>\1<_blue>"

sed -e "s|\($PREFIX$TARGET_1\)|$SUB_1|" \
    -e "s|\($PREFIX$TARGET_2\)|$SUB_2|" \
    -e "s|\($PREFIX\(.*&!$TARGET_1&!$TARGET_2\)\)|$SUB_3|" \
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other errorcodes follow the naming scheme errcodeN, you can negate the 1,2:

```
sed -e "s|\(Error=errcode1\)|<red>\1<_red>|" \
    -e "s|\(Error=errcode2\)|<orange>\1<_orange>|" \
    -e "s|\(Error=errcode[^12]\)|<blue>\1<_blue>|"
```

If the codes exceed number 9: `[^12]+`

Comment: How is `errorcode[^12]` in your answer equivalent to `*` in the OP's question? You will miss all strings like `Error=UserUnknown`.

Comment: I don't have secret insights into the patterns of the other errorcodes. Maybe errorcode10?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good application for sed, you should use awk instead. You didn't provide any sample input/output to test against so this is obviously untested but you'd do something like this:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    colors["errorcode1"] = "red"
    colors["errorcode2"] = "orange"
    colors["default"]    = "blue"
}
match($0,/(.*Error=)([[:alnum:]]+)(.*)/,a) {
    code  = a[2]
    color = (code in colors ? colors[code] : colors["default"])
    $0    = sprintf("%s<%s>%s<_%s>%s", a[1], color, code, color, a[3])
}
{ print }
'
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), it's a minor tweak for other awks.